# Lindenbaum lemma and non-monotonic logics

Tags: lo.logic

Is it possible to apply [Lindenbaum's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%27s_lemma) to non-monotonic *propositional* logics to prove completeness theorem? To be more specific, for a given non-monotonic deductive system is it always possible to extend a consistent set to a maximal consistent set **which is also deductively closed**?

The reason for asking this question is that I was recently going through a PhD thesis where the author has proven completeness theorems for different non-monotonic *propositional* deductive systems. However all of these proofs involve the construction of [Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra). I was wondering whether we can imitate the usual proof of completeness theorem of classical propositional logic (by Lindenbaum lemma) to non-monotonic logics also.

Comment: Out of curiosity, whose thesis was this?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: One of my senior who is also the student of my co-guide.

Comment: Noam's question is probably: what is the name of the author of this thesis.

Comment: In that case, sorry @Noah, I can't reveal her identity because that has the potential to reveal my identity also (which defeats the purpose of remaining anonymous).

Comment: If you had just told us her name instead of her relationship to you, no one would  be able to work out your identity...